# How to check in Java if a number is a cube

Tags: java, math

In Java how do you check if a number is a cube ?

The number can be between the range `−2,147,483,648..2,147,483,647`

Say for instance given the following numbers we can see that they are cubes

```
8 (2^3) - True
27 (3^3) - True
64 (4^3) - True
```

Comment: thats what i mean sorry.

Comment: changed the question to reflect it

Comment: And in general this kind of check is a mathematical problem not a software one.  While there is occasionally a "trick" or two one can use, they don't tend to be language-specific.

Comment: @nachokk - I think he'd have to use cube root.  And since the implementation of cube root would be floating-point, an integer result is not guaranteed.

Comment: @HotLicks: rounding it to the nearest int should fix it though, right? The margin of error shouldn't be as high as .5.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - I don't see how.

Comment: @HotLicks  `double x=Math.cbrt(input); x == Math.rint(x)` this won't work?

Comment: @nachokk - What you gotta do is take the cube root, round, then cube the number and see if you get the original number.

Answer (score 5):

(-1291)^3 and 1291^3 are both already outside the range of an `int` in Java. So there are 2581 such numbers anyway. Honestly a lookup table might be the easiest and fastest thing.

Comment: Small remark: 1290^3=2146689000 < Integer.MAX_VALUE (and -1290^3 > MIN_VALUE)

Comment: Oops! yeah they're the last cubes *not* outside this range. I'll fix.

Answer (score 2):

Try some `Math` (`java.lang.Math`):

```
boolean isCube(double input) {
    double cubeRoot = Math.cbrt(input); // get the cube root
    return Math.round(cubeRoot) == cubeRoot; // determine if number is integral
    // Sorry for the stupid integrity determination. I tried to answer fast 
    // and really couldn't remember the better way to do that :)
}
```

Comment: Note that this declares `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` a cube. Not that that's any more correct than declaring it not a cube

Comment: @Eric of course user must read some javadoc to deal with such special cases. But overall it is better than inventig a new bicycle.

Comment: You're assuming that the cube root routine will be exact for integers.  It can be off by one ulp.

Comment: I tried it and it does work for all `int`s, and well past it actually.

Answer (score 2):

Try to take a cubic root, round the result and take its cube:

```
int a = (int) Math.round(Math.pow(number_to_test, 1.0/3.0));
return (number_to_test == a * a * a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do the following (pseudocode)

```
double x = number;
int b = floor (x ^ (1.0/3.0))  // ^ is exponentiation
if (b*b*b == number || (b+1)*(b+1)*(b+1) == number)
    // it is a cube
```

Comment: // ^ is not exponentiation in Java -- Math.pow() is. And there's a Math.cbrt() function.

Comment: @SeanOwen I made it a habit to not write copy-pasteable code on SO. Like it or not. Besides, the java language is not suitable to convey a mathematical idea, so I prefer a more relaxed notation.

Comment: @Ingo: `import static java.lang.Math.*` gets you pretty close

Comment: This isn't pseudo-code to me, since it's 90% the way to Java and formatted to be code. I think it's more confusing on SO to paste almost-Java. Why write b*b*b instead of b^3 for example, if this is the logic?

Answer (score -2):

Add a loop:

```
int inputNum = //whatever ;
int counter = 1;
boolean po3 = false;
while(counter<inputNum || po3==true){
 if((counter*counter*counter)==inputNum){
  po3 = true;
 } else {
  counter++;
 }
}
```

Comment: This misses 0 and negative values, and continues far too long -- after counter^3 exceeds inputNum you can stop.